# http response not returning back upon 503 status code - multi thread issue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient, executorservice, http-status-code-503

I am using executor service with fixed thread pool which submits future task for creating xml files.
Each time it fetches xml from the url, generates xml and compares with the existing xml to find whether there is any mismatch. I have provided the fetchAPIData method as synchronized to make it thread safe - but it reduces the performance drastically.To avoid thread interruped exception and make it thread safe, i have set connectionpoolmanager while building the httpclient.
The problem i am facing is that when the server hits 503, it reconnects the session and retries to connect. Once the 503 is hit, it retries and sends the response but the program doesnot seems to exit at the end.It seems waiting for responses from some thread response endlessely.Following is my code.I have tried

fetchAPIData:-

```
public String fetchAPIData(URI uri) throws ClarityAPIValidatorException {

        int retryCount = 0;
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = buildHttpResponse(uri,
                getClientContext(), getHttpClient());

        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        try {
            switch (statusCode) {
                /*StatusCode - 200*/
                case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
                    return outputBasedOnStatusCode(httpResponse);
                /*StatusCode - 401*/
                case HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED:
                    logger.info(ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.RESPONSE_CODE + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " +
                            ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.URL + uri);
                    createSessionWithCookies(new URI(ClarityAPIProperties.getApiBaseURL()));
                    httpResponse = buildHttpResponse(uri, getClientContext(),
                            getHttpClient());
                    return outputBasedOnStatusCode(httpResponse);
                /*StatusCode - 503*/
                case HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:

                        do {
                            logger.info(ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.RESPONSE_CODE + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " +
                                    ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.URL + uri);
                            retryCount++;
                            this.pause(httpResponse, retryCount);
                            logger.info(ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.REQ_EXECUTING + uri);
                            createSessionWithCookies(uri);
                            httpResponse = buildHttpResponse(uri,
                                    getClientContext(), getHttpClient());
                            logger.info(ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.RETRY + ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.RESPONSE_CODE + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

                        }
                        while (isRetryRequired(httpResponse, retryCount));
                        return outputBasedOnStatusCode(httpResponse);
                /*StatusCode other than 200, 401 and 503*/
                default:
                    throw new ClarityAPIValidatorException(UN_HANDLED_RES_TYPE +
                            statusCode + PATH + uri.getPath());
            }
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

createsessioncookie

```
 public void createSessionWithCookies(URI uri) throws ClarityAPIValidatorException {
        CredentialsProvider provider =
                buildCredentialsProvider(ClarityAPIProperties.getApiUsername(),
                        ClarityAPIProperties.getApiPassword());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = buildHttpClient(provider);
        HttpClientContext clientContext = buildHttpClientContext(uri, provider);

        if (httpClient == null || clientContext == null) {
            throw new ClarityAPIValidatorException(CREATE_SESSION_ERROR);
        } else {
            this.setHttpClient(httpClient);
            this.setClientContext(clientContext);
        }
    }
```

buildHttpClient :-

```
 public CloseableHttpClient buildHttpClient(CredentialsProvider provider) {
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                .build();
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager =
                new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        
        return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .build();
    }
```

buildHttpResponse:-

```
public  CloseableHttpResponse buildHttpResponse(URI uri,
                                                   HttpClientContext clientContext,
                                                   CloseableHttpClient httpClient)
            throws ClarityAPIValidatorException {

        HttpGet httpGet = buildHttpRequest(uri);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, clientContext);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClarityAPIValidatorException(GET_REQ_FAIL + uri.getPath());
        }

        if (isNull(response))
            throw new ClarityAPIValidatorException(RES_NULL + uri.getPath());

        return response;
    }
```

isRetryRequired:- max retry is 5 with 5sec,10sec....upto 25 sec

```
 public boolean isRetryRequired(CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse,
                                   int retryCount) {
        return httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE &&
                retryCount < ClarityAPIValidatorConstants.RETRY_MAX_COUNT;


    }
```

Comment: can you attach the body of isRetryRequired method ?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Have you taken a thread dump at the point in time at which your program is failing to stop?

Comment: no...but when i take the count, 2 xml files are not generated